# How to create Drupal view to show CiviEvents and Drupal Events

Tags: civievent, drupal, drupal-views

I'm trying to create a view to show both CiviEvents and Drupal Events filtered by dates.

I can create a Drupal view to show Drupal Events fields, and I can create a view to show CiviEvent fields, but I can't create a view to show both.

Am I missing something obvious here or is it not possible due to the two databases?

We are using Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.7.24. We have separate databases and have the CiviCRM Entity module installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are missing anything obvious. They are completely different Entity Types so you can't do this in a single view.

This is a constraint of Views.

If you were to create a Drupal node linked to each CiviEvent (using CiviCRM Entities) then you would be able to display all items as 'content' and provide links to the Info and Registration pages from that.

There has been some good documentation about doing that by [skvare.com](https://skvare.com/blog/using-civicrm-entity-reference-field-submodule-inline-entity-form?utm_source=CiviCRM&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=civicrm_entity_reference)

Comment: Peter is right. On your event node create an entityreference field that targets civicrm events.